# Curl data and combine it with Rails Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl

Maybe it sounds stupid but I am a newbie on RoR and really eager to learn.

There are 3 dropdown lists on a web page where I can get data by using terminal `curl ... --data` e.g: Car brand, year and model, and then I would like to create a database by using RoR with the datas from terminal.

I do not know if thats possible. As an example,

[image: Shown how it looks like]

But Imagine I have 100 sections so I would like to create a database with the data I can get from terminal.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the command line in Ruby (and therefore Rails) using backticks (`), or the commands `system` or `shell`, or in various other ways.

So, you could do

```
response = `curl #{url}`
```

inside your rails code (model or controller), and parse the results.  However, there are a variety of gems already available for pulling html from somewhere (a text file or a webpage via url for example), and extracting content out of it, which are more reliable and easier to use than curl.  This process is called "scraping", so a google for "scrape website rails" will get you started.

Nokogiri is a popular choice - eg http://ruby.bastardsbook.com/chapters/html-parsing/

Answer (score 2):

Ruby has several libraries to get data over the net such as [Net::HTTP (included in ruby)](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html), [Typheos](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus) and [Faraday](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday).

Getting data can be as simple as:

```
require 'net/http'
uri = URI('http://example.com/index.html?count=10')
Net::HTTP.get(uri) # => String
```

But at your skill level you should perhaps consider taking a few and [Ruby](http://tryruby.org/) and [Rails](https://www.railstutorial.org/) tutorials before you tackle this project.